# Contact layout editor db update crash on upgrade to 1.2.1

Tags: drupal, contact-layout-editor

I upgraded a site to 5.7 and got a message to upgrade the contact layout editor to 1.2.1. After installation a database update has to be run which stops with the message ***[Error: Upgrade org.civicrm.contactlayout to revision 1000]
DB Error: no such field***
I tried again on another site and got the same problem.  Uninstalling & re-installing the extension fixed the problem, but that might not suit those who had made many changes.  Is there a fix for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing out the bug in the upgrade code. I've pushed up a fix and published a new release: 1.2.2.

https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.contactlayout/releases/tag/1.2.2